# What happened to tux4ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, launcher, plymouth

I was just wondering if someone could tell me what happened to tux4ubuntu? I did a clean install today and was about to change back to the tux boot animation but now the blog doesn't exist. Any idea what happened?

Also if someone has the tux4ubuntu, please upload and share a link here as I am in desperate need of those files, especially the boot animation and the tux logo in the launcher icon. Other plymouth suggestions are welcome too.
Also Pardon my English too :)

Comment: The project appears to be dead.

Comment: Any links to it? I just need it's plymouth theme

Comment: I don't see what use dead links to a dead project would be.  It was once [here](https://github.com/tuxedojoe/tux4ubuntu)

Comment: I know it's been a while, but I believe rEFInd was at the base of it. You can always install rEFInd 
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind 
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get install refind 

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Answer (score 0):

Tux4Ubuntu temporarily closed down for a while but I'm happy to announce that it's relaunching with an updated 2.0 version in a couple of weeks. But all functionality are already there and ready for installation so you can get it running just as easy as before.

Check it out on the new website at https://tux4ubuntu.org

And please comment bugs/tips etc so it can be even better in the future.